# Old house - hanging a new light fixture

Tags: wiring

I have 1 red wire and a neutral wire attached to the fixture and the black wire do not attached to anything, how do I install a new light fixture with a black wire a white wire and the copper ground wire?[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Generally, you would leave the black alone, hook white to white and (new) black to red. It depends on how its wired beyond that box. I assume that this is possibly part or a 3-way circuit...or a xx/3 cable was used and there could have been a different unit there before.

Comment: Can you post a photo looking up into the box?

Answer (score 3):

#### Rule # 1 - When making a replacement, don't touch anything else.

In this case, that means you **only** use the wires connected to the old fixture - white (neutral) and red (switched hot). Ignore the other white wires and the black wires.

#### Rule # 2 - In the US, Hot/Switched Hot can be **ANY** color except white (neutral), gray (neutral), green (ground), bare wire (ground).

In this case, that means **red** == **black**.

#### Rule # 3 - All grounds go together and can include metal boxes & conduit.

This one is a little tricky. If there are no ground wires then that *should* mean that your metal junction box is connected to metal conduit all the way back to the panel. If that's the case then you can ground the new fixture using a [grounding screw](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Ideal-Combo-Grounding-Screw-10-Card-774042/100134430).

The big question, of course, is whether or not the metal box is truly grounded. If you see metal conduit "everywhere" then that is a very good sign. If not, there are ways to test (essentially, if everything is wired correctly then "ground" == "metal box" to "hot" should read ~ 120V and "ground" == "metal box" to "neutral" should be almost no resistance).

End result:

- White (new fixture) => white (ceiling)
- Black (new fixture) => red (ceiling)
- Bare ground (new fixture) => green/bare ground **or** metal box (ceiling)